# Add trigger to every UserControl

Tags: wpf, xaml

My application has about 15 different UserControls that are uniformly loaded into a content-area at runtime.

My project is 100% MVVM-compliant, so I have the following XAML inserted into every UserControl's XAML:

```
<UserControl
    ...
    xmlns:intr="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
>

    <intr:Interaction.Triggers>
        <intr:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <intr:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ViewLoadedCommand}"/>
        </intr:EventTrigger>
    </intr:Interaction.Triggers>

    <!-- Rest of UserControl content here -->

</UserControl>
```

Obviously this isn't ideal and is also a violation of DRY.

What is the best way to have this XAML applied to this set of UserControls? (but not **every** UserControl, so a simple `<Style Type="UserControl" />` would be inappropriate).

Comment: Why not style with a key?

Comment: @Nikita Actually, I don't know how to author a style that sets composite and complex attachment-properties like `Interaction.Triggers`.

Comment: Where is ViewLoadedCommand located? Is this in your view model? Are you sure you want to be calling this command **every time** a user control is loaded?

Comment: @MikeEason Correct, it's a `RelayCommand` and yes, I want it to be called on every load, it's a surrogate for `OnLoaded`.

Comment: Seems like that is impossible, we need to check for a work around.

Comment: you can define a DataTemplate with interaction triggers & a ContentControl (binded to the Content of Self). Assign this as dataTemplate for the usercontrols where you need the triggers - Just a wild guess :P

Answer (score 4):

I use behavior implemented as attached property. It has two major advantages over System.Windows.Interactivity:

- it can be defined in style.
- much less xaml code in the views

in your case, the view could look like:

```
<UserControl ...
             my:AttachedCommands.LoadedCommand="{Binding ViewLoadedCommand}">
```

In my solution, I'm not using commands, but I call methods on viewmodel if the viewmodel implements `IViewModelLifeCycle` interface:

```
public interface IViewModelLifeCycle
{
    void Activate(object extraData);
    void Deactivate();
}
```

All my views uses this style:

```
<Style x:Key="ViewBaseStyle">
    <Setter Property="my:ViewModelLifeCycleBehavior.ActivateOnLoad" Value="True" />
```

and the behavior:

```
public static class ViewModelLifeCycleBehavior
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ActivateOnLoadProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ActivateOnLoad", typeof (bool), typeof (ViewModelLifeCycleBehavior),
        new PropertyMetadata(ActivateOnLoadPropertyChanged));

    public static void SetActivateOnLoad(FrameworkElement element, bool value)
    {
        element.SetValue(ActivateOnLoadProperty, value);
    }

    public static bool GetActivateOnLoad(FrameworkElement element)
    {
        return (bool)element.GetValue(ActivateOnLoadProperty);
    }


    private static void ActivateOnLoadPropertyChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    { 
        if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(obj)) return;
        var element = (FrameworkElement)obj;

        element.Loaded -= ElementLoaded;
        element.Unloaded -= ElementUnloaded;

        if ((bool) args.NewValue == true)
        {
            element.Loaded += ElementLoaded;
            element.Unloaded += ElementUnloaded;
        }
    }



    static void ElementLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var element = (FrameworkElement) sender;
        var viewModel = (IViewModelLifeCycle) element.DataContext;
        if (viewModel == null)
        {
            DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler dataContextChanged = null;
            dataContextChanged = (o, _e) =>
            {
                ElementLoaded(sender, e);
                element.DataContextChanged -= dataContextChanged;
            };
            element.DataContextChanged += dataContextChanged;
        }
        else if (element.ActualHeight > 0 && element.ActualWidth > 0) //to avoid activating twice since loaded event is called twice on TabItems' subtrees
        {
            viewModel.Activate(null);
        } 
    }

    private static void ElementUnloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var element = (FrameworkElement)sender;
        var viewModel = (IViewModelLifeCycle)element.DataContext;
        viewModel.Deactivate();
    }


}
```

**TIP:**
Create your [custom Item Template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tsyyf0yh.aspx) in Visual Studio for View and ViewModel. its very easy and saves a lot of time. The item template can contain xaml code with the trigger/behaviour, pointing to your base style, your `d:DataContext` definition and your viewmodel class.

Answer (score 0):

you could create a "base-load" Usercontrol with the Interaction.Triggers and just put a ContentPresenter in it where you bind the real content to.

```
<UserControl x:class="OneOfMyOtherControls">
   <MyBaseUserControl>
     <!-- your UserControl Content-->
   </MyBaseUserControl>
</UserControl>
```